# From string to float python

Tags: python, string, floating-point, type-conversion, valueerror

I want to make a code to read files that contain data from a sensor.  I got stuck at the start:

```
    import numpy as np

a = []
b = []
x = []
y = []
for line in open("YAZID.txt", "r"):
    lines = [i for i in line.split()]
    print(lines)
    a.append(float(lines[0]))
    b.append(float(lines[1]))
for i in a:
    i = float(i)
    x.append(i)
print(x)
```

it gives me this error

```
    ['0,375', '7,84E-02']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\pc orange\Desktop\graphs\graph.py", line 32, in <module>
    a.append(float(lines[0]))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0,375'
```

they get stuck at being strings

is there a way to make them into float so that i can make a plot with them the numbers are really little and i need to read the whole number each time

Comment: Do ```a.append(float(lines[0].replace(',','.'))```

Comment: @Sujay I had already answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68644312/12446721). :)

Comment: @Xitiz oh! It did not update here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace that `,` with `.` and then try the same thing. Here's the code:

```
for line in open("YAZID.txt", "r"):
    lines = [i for i in line.split()]
    print(lines)
    a.append(float(lines[0].replace(",",".")))
    b.append(float(lines[1].replace(",",".")))
```

Doing this should work for you.

And additionally at last you don't have to make that `float` again, doing just this is okay.

```
for i in a:
    x.append(i)
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string= "3.141"

print(string)
print(type(string))

# converting string to float
Float = float(string)

print(Float)
print(type(Float))
```

Answer (score 0):

the probleme was in my text file the comas were comas(,) not points(.) also used this code to make them into float

```
 x = [float(c) for c in a]
```

thanks everyone for your help

Comment: But your error is in `a.append(float(lines[0].replace(",",".")))` so this is not technically an answer! And if you follow my answer  while appending in `a` then you don't have to do this as well. I had mentioned that too in my answer! I had already answered your full questions, I don't think you have to write a new answer, you can accept my answer and it is officially your problem solution!

Comment: i am quite new in here so i am stiill not accustumed to how it works here i used your answer and it did the job thank you